# Django - How to import a model from another app into another app's views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working in an app called 'lineup', and I have another app called 'market' that has a model called 'Inventory' which I need to import into the lineup app's views.py

How can I do that?

Comment: `from market.models import Inventory`

Comment: @Razenstein that worked, tysm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`from market.models import Inventory`

Comment: what do you mean with update? .models should only import from models.py in same folder and therefore not work for other apps like asked here.

Comment: Adding to the comment I made above ^
the method that worked is the first one.